# Hadoop Hive: find all occurrences of a string in all columns in all tables?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

Need advice on approach and tools for the following task.

Input: Hive DB with approx. 100 tables. Mean table length is 5 000 000 rows. Mean number of columns in a table is 40. Tables have all different types of fields including string type.

Task:

1.Find all strings containing given sub-string in all columns in all tables. Strings thus found are called search strings.

2.Create table with two columns: search string and list of `table.field` strings indicating where search string was found.

To solve this I plan to use map-reduce on Hive tables. Yet, it looks like there are some limitations:

- Only one input table can be set for MRD job in Java program:

  `HCatInputFormat.setInput(job, InputJobInfo.create(dbName, inputTableName, null));`
- When my MRD job tries to append data to the *an existing non-empty* output table (already filled with records by this very job on the previous run!) I get exception:

  `ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:TestUser (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hcatalog.common.HCatException : 2003 : Non-partitioned table already contains data ...`

Questions:

- How to write Java MRD job that runs on several input Hive tables?
- How to write Java MRD job to append data to an existing non-empty Hive table?
- How to get DB and table name in Java MRD job that runs on input Hive table?

Thanks!